# rc-slider icon or html label

Tags: reactjs, rc-slider

I use re-slider in my react app, someone know if it's possible to set label with icon/html ?

I tried to define option as follow:

```
const sliderOptions = {
  1: {
    style: {
      color: '#00365f',
    },
    label: '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>',
  },1: {
    style: {
      color: '#00365f',
    },
    label: '<i class="fas fa-times"></i>',
  }           
};
```

but html tags has been transformed in entity

```
&lt;i class="fas fa-check"&gt;&lt;/i&gt;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [example documentation](https://github.com/react-component/slider/blob/master/examples/marks.js#L8):

```
const marks = {
  '-10': '-10°C',
  0: <strong>0°C</strong>,
  26: '26°C',
  37: '37°C',
  50: '50°C',
  100: {
    style: {
      color: 'red',
    },
    label: <strong>100°C</strong>,
  },
};
```

Don't include it as a string, instead include it as a DOM/React Node:

```
const sliderOptions = {
  1: {
    style: {
      color: '#00365f',
    },
    label: <i className="fas fa-check"></i>,
  },1: {
    style: {
      color: '#00365f',
    },
    label: <i className="fas fa-times"></i>,
  }           
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the sample code for your demo.

```
<Slider
  min={0}
  max={100}
  step={10}
  marks={{
    0: 0,
    30: <p style={{ color: 'green', fontSize: 20 }}>30</p>,
    50: <input type="button" value="50 hit" />,
    70: <i className="fas fa-3x fa-check"></i>,
    100: <i className="fas fa-2x fa-times"></i>
  }}
/>
```

Output will be look like below

[image]